# Logging and performing mathmatical calc. during run?

Tags: ev3, education

Is it possible using the new EV3 to log data, and peform mathmatical calculation on the data while it's being logged, and peform some and thereby trigger some event if some value has been reached??

As far i can see, it is possible doing seperatly..

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the datalog block from education version, you can create a custom version using the file access block. It's a bit more difficult, but more flexible...
You won't be able to directly use EV3 datalog management, but you can structure the file to be directly compatible with csv format, readable by spreadsheet programs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Philo mentioned, the EV3's native datalog block is very limited. Instead, you can use the File Access block and then export it to your computer.

CSV Format is as follows:

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```