# Could I do datalogging in Mindstorms EV3 Home edition?

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

Apparently datalogging is an integrated part of the educational EV3 software. But I got the Home edition. Is there some module or thing I can use to get datalogging functionality in my Home edition?

Or do I need to build it myself?

Comment: Seems like this could be a solution: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2815/5687

Comment: I believe the data logging component is actually a feature of the Firmware for the EV3 brick, in conjunction with some additional capabilities of the main software to load additional modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data logging is one of the things you are paying extra for when you purchase the Education software. Data logging is turned off in the Home version frimware and there is no means to configure data logging using the Home version software.

The firmware is open source, so technically, you could download it, figure out how to build it and turn on the data logging in the firmware, but then you would still need to reverse engineer a way to configure it.

If you don't need a very high sample rate (10-15 samples per second or less, probably), you could come up with something using an existing remote control library to log the data via USB or Bluetooth. For example, LeJOS and MonoBrick both have remote control libraries that would make it easy to write your own data logging program.

For a higher sample rate, you could write a program that runs on the brick using a 3rd party firmware/SD card image.

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, you can do data logging on your home edition. The firmware is capable to run programs that have been created on the education edition and contain the block "Data logging". In this block you define which sensor is logged etc. When the program runs it creates a log file on the brick. This file contains the logged data. The file contains some binary data for each log value, you have to figure out the format of it to change it to readable data.

Once you open a program containing the "Data logging" block on your home edition, you will be able to copy and change this block in any way.

Here is a Project containing the "Data logging" block: http://1drv.ms/1EcmjGD

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could. If you can get your hands on the education software, you can upload the EV3 education firmware onto the home edition brick. Here are the steps:

- Shut off brick
- Hold down right and middle buttons
- When it says updating..
- Then plug into computer with the educational version of software
- Open up Tools
- Firmware update
- Click on firmware update….choose recent version
- Click download

Tried it on my home EV3 and converted it to education.. Now data logging is present and works.